# Different sensitivity when zooming in

Tags: controllers, destiny

Is it possible to adjust the "look-around sensitivity" for when zooming in and not zooming in with a weapon in Destiny?

I know I can change the sensitivity for both but I want to have slow when zooming in and fast when not zooming.

Comment: I don't believe so, the options for Destiny are fairly limited in regards to changing controls and audio/visual aspects. Not posting as an answer since I am not able to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to adjust the sensitivity. I avidly use a sniper rifle (Patience & Time) in the crucible and elsewhere.

[image]

At one point I extensively looked for a sensitivity differential setting when I first started playing. It isn't there.

The advice I would offer is to simply start getting used to higher sensitivity. I have currently worked my way up to 7 (the default is 3). Don't skip too many at once or it can be a little jarring. It definitely helps with snapshots, people trying to blink shotgun over/through you, melee attacks, and quick maneuvers through obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change it. Your look sensivity changes both, but, your weapon handling is what changes zoom look speed. When you have a perk on said weapon that says "makes weapon heavy" or "snappy" or "improves weapon handling. These change the zoom look speed. So a snappy scope will increase zoom look speed and a heavy scope will decrease zoom look speed. So for your case you will want a heavy scope.

Answer (score 0):

Like what was said in the other answer you can't configure the zoomed in sensitivity as a game setting.

However rare or better guns roll multiple sight options. Different sights have different sensitivities.  An Eagle Eye SLR20 will handle heavy and slow.  An Ambush SLH25 will aim more snappy.

The names will vary, but you want one with a description that contains this:

> Heavy optics for pinpoint sniping.

If you don't have a gun with a heavy scope, you can re-roll Legendary guns at the gunsmith to try for different perks.